# I need to use double() in my Transpose Java program and use scanner as well

Tags: java, matrix, input, double, transpose

I'm trying to write a program that takes a first input of the transpose size (n X n) and then takes inputs for the matrix elements, But I need the elements to be double instead of integers, and I keep getting an error (that I should replace the double to int).
How can I fix it please; I'm a new Java learner.
Thanks a lot in advance
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class transpose_test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int tra_size;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What size does the transpose have (n X n): ");
        tra_size=sc.nextInt();
        int a[][]=new int[tra_size][tra_size];
        System.out.println("Input the elements of matrix (a):");
        for(double i=0; i<tra_size; i++) {
            for(double j=0; j<tra_size; j++) {
                System.out.print("a [" + (i) + "],[" + (j) + "] = ");
                a[i][j] = sc.nextDouble(); // Keeps telling me to chanege the double into int
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Matrix a:");
        for(double i=0; i<tra_size; i++){
            for(double j=0; j<tra_size; j++){
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("The Transpose Matrix is");
        for(double i=0; i<tra_size; i++){
            for(double j=0; j<tra_size; j++){
                System.out.print(a[j][i] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to be clear about:

1. The indices of your array are NOT doubles. They are integers. So, while traversing through the arrays, use `int i` instead of `double i`.
2. You're storing doubles as your inputs, so your 2D array should be of `double` type and not `int`.

Here is the formatted code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("What size does the transpose have (n X n): ");
int tra_size = sc.nextInt();

//changed from int to double
double[][] a = new double[tra_size][tra_size];
System.out.println("Input the elements of matrix (a):");

//int instead of double
for (int i = 0; i < tra_size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tra_size; j++) {
        System.out.printf("a [%d],[%d] = ", i, j);
        a[i][j] = sc.nextDouble();
    }
}
System.out.println("Matrix a: ");

//int instead of double
for (int i = 0; i < tra_size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tra_size; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("The Transpose Matrix is");

//int instead of double
for (int i = 0; i < tra_size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tra_size; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[j][i] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the for loops you are checking from 0 to the matrix size. That should be `int` .  The problem is your type of 2d array . If you want elements of `double` data type then you need to declare the array as `double`.

```
 double a [][]=new double [tra_size][tra_size]
```

Try this code .This wills sort out your problem

```
    int tra_size;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What size does the transpose have (n X n): ");
    tra_size=sc.nextInt();
    double a [][]=new double [tra_size][tra_size];
    System.out.println("Input the elements of matrix (a):");
    for(int i=0; i<tra_size; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<tra_size; j++) {
            System.out.print("a [" + (i) + "],[" + (j) + "] = ");
            a[i][j] = sc.nextDouble(); // Keeps telling me to chanege the double into int
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Matrix a:");
    for(int i=0; i<tra_size; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<tra_size; j++){
            System.out.print(a[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("The Transpose Matrix is");
    for(int i=0; i<tra_size; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<tra_size; j++){
            System.out.print(a[j][i] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I **think** I see the confusion, the ***indices*** of arrays should not be `double` (they should be `int`). The elements of the array `a` should be `double` (`double[][]` not `int[][]`). Like,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("What size does the transpose have (n X n): ");
int tra_size = sc.nextInt();
double[][] a = new double[tra_size][tra_size];
System.out.println("Input the elements of matrix (a):");
for (int i = 0; i < tra_size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tra_size; j++) {
        System.out.printf("a [%d],[%d] = ", i, j);
        a[i][j] = sc.nextDouble();
    }
}
System.out.println("Matrix a: ");
for (int i = 0; i < tra_size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tra_size; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("The Transpose Matrix is");
for (int i = 0; i < tra_size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tra_size; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[j][i] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```